# How to fix child node snapshot issue with ARKitSample project?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, arkit

I've downloaded the ARKitSample project with the ship from - https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ios11/ARKitSample/ARKitSample/GameViewController.cs

After running the code, it works as expected until I tap on the screen, the gesture recognize event is called and it works fine the first time - I get a plane node with a snapshot of the screen. But when this is called the second time, instead of creating a new node at the location of the second tap, it overlaps the initial child node.

The code is a port of the original swift version from the ARKit keynote here - https://youtu.be/LLRweyZ1KpA?t=1380

```cs
private void HandleTap(UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognize)
{
    // Get current frame
    var currentFrame = SceneView.Session.CurrentFrame;
    if (currentFrame == null) return;

    // Create an image plane using a snapshot of the view
    var imagePlane = SCNPlane.Create(SceneView.Bounds.Width / 6000, SceneView.Bounds.Height / 6000);
    imagePlane.FirstMaterial.Diffuse.Contents = SceneView.Snapshot();
    imagePlane.FirstMaterial.LightingModelName = SCNLightingModel.Constant;

    // Create a plane node and add it to the scene
    var planeNode = SCNNode.FromGeometry(imagePlane);
    SceneView.Scene.RootNode.AddChildNode(planeNode);

    // Set transform of node to be 10cm in front of the camera
    var translation = SCNMatrix4.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0.1f);
    var cameraTranslation = currentFrame.Camera.Transform.ToSCNMatrix4();
    planeNode.Transform = SCNMatrix4.Mult(cameraTranslation, translation);
}
```

I've tried this on an iPhone XS and 7, am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Hi, did it solve your issues?

Answer (score 0):

The sample changes the node's transform for you. If you want to change the node's position, you can try the code below:

```
var tapLocation = gestureRecognize.LocationInView(SceneView);
var hitTestResults = SceneView.HitTest(tapLocation, ARHitTestResultType.EstimatedHorizontalPlane);

var hitTestResult = hitTestResults.FirstOrDefault();
if (hitTestResult == null) return;
var position = new SCNVector3(hitTestResult.WorldTransform.Column3.X, hitTestResult.WorldTransform.Column3.Y, hitTestResult.WorldTransform.Column3.Z);
planeNode.Position = position;
```